# C# LibCurlNet Image Upload

Tags: c#, php, curl

Hi I have the following code which actually create a `CurlFile Object` and post an image to the server. It works perfectly on php

```
$post_data = array('device_timestamp' => time());
$post_data['photo'] = "@".realpath('imagePath');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

However I want to achieve the same with c# LibCurNet. What I have tried so far are below

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StreamContent(File.Open(@"D:\mypictres\p.JPG", FileMode.Open)), "photo", "Image.JPG");
content.Add(new StringContent("mobiletime"), "1526137643");

easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POST, 
easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, content );
```

and

```
public class postData
{
        public string device_timestamp { get; set; }
        public string photo { get; set; }
}
```

using as

```
 postData p = new postData();
 p.device_timestamp = "1526137643";
 p.photo = @"D:\mypictures\p.JPG";
 easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POST, 
 easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, p);
```

I am literally banging my head for what would the replacement for `CurlFileObject` in c#. I dont want to use `HttpWebRequest` or `HttpClient` for some reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me we are on the same path lol. try the following code.

```
MultiPartForm mf = new MultiPartForm();

mf.AddSection(CURLformoption.CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "name",
CURLformoption.CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "value",
CURLformoption.CURLFORM_END);



mf.AddSection(CURLformoption.CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "photo",
CURLformoption.CURLFORM_FILE, @"yourpicturepath",
CURLformoption.CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "multipart/form-data",
CURLformoption.CURLFORM_END);

easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, mf);
```

Comment: is this should be multipart/form-data or application/binary ?